# How to fetch older webrtc revision and compile for arm64

Tags: ios, webrtc, arm64

Is it possible to use "fetch webrtc" to get an older webrtc revision (maybe with some flag/option ) and then compile it for arm64?

I tried pulling an older revision with `gclient sync --force -r 6881`, but got an error while compiling.

I know its kind of an old revision but, still, if possible I would like to compile that specific one for arm64.

This is what i did:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH="$PATH":`pwd`/depot_tools
gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
echo "target_os = ['ios']" >> .gclient
export GYP_DEFINES="OS=ios"
gclient sync --force -r 6881
```

This is pulling the correct trunk (running 'svn checkout http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk@6881...)

```
export GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1
export GYP_DEFINES=“build_with_libjingle=1 clang=1 component=static_library dcheck_always_on=1 fastbuild=0 OS=ios target_arch=arm64 target_subarch=arm64”
export GYP_GENERATOR_FLAGS=“output_dir=out_ios64"
export GYP_GENERATORS=“ninja"
cd trunk
gclient runhooks
ninja -C out_ios64/Release-iphoneos AppRTCDemo
```

i got this error:

```
Admins-Mac-mini:trunk admin$ ninja -C out_ios64/Release-iphoneos AppRTCDemo
ninja: Entering directory `out_ios64/Release-iphoneos'
[206/1912] CXX obj/third_party/libyuv/source/libyuv.scale_argb.o
FAILED: c++ -MMD -MF obj/third_party/libyuv/source/libyuv.scale_argb.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DBLINK_SCALE_FILTERS_AT_RECORD_TIME -DDISABLE_NACL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=214024 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DDISCARDABLE_MEMORY_ALWAYS_SUPPORTED_NATIVELY -DSYSTEM_NATIVELY_SIGNALS_MEMORY_PRESSURE -DDCHECK_ALWAYS_ON=1 -DENABLE_EGLIMAGE=1 -DCLD_VERSION=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DDISABLE_FTP_SUPPORT=1 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -Igen -I../../third_party/libyuv/include -I../../third_party/libyuv -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -Os -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -Wnewline-eof -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -arch arm64 -Wendif-labels -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-selector-type-mismatch -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -std=gnu++0x -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-slp-vectorize -fcolor-diagnostics  -c ../../third_party/libyuv/source/scale_argb.cc -o obj/third_party/libyuv/source/libyuv.scale_argb.o
../../third_party/libyuv/source/scale_argb.cc:150:26: error: assigning to 'void (*)(const uint8 *, ptrdiff_t, int, uint8 *, int)' from incompatible type 'void (const uint8 *, int, int, uint8 *, int)': type mismatch at 2nd parameter ('ptrdiff_t' (aka 'long') vs 'int')
    ScaleARGBRowDownEven = filtering ? ScaleARGBRowDownEvenBox_NEON :
                         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[206/1912] LINK libvpx_obj_int_extract, POSTBUILDS
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I think I'm missing some dependencies (maybe because its an old trunk) but not sure.

Also for `ios target_arch=armv7` it compiles fine.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Pulling a slightly newer revision (r6915) didn't help:

There is still some error with libvpx library

```
[58/1912] CXX obj/third_party/libyuv/source/libyuv.scale_argb.o
FAILED: c++ -MMD -MF obj/third_party/libyuv/source/libyuv.scale_argb.o.d -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DDISABLE_NACL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=214024 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DDISCARDABLE_MEMORY_ALWAYS_SUPPORTED_NATIVELY -DSYSTEM_NATIVELY_SIGNALS_MEMORY_PRESSURE -DDCHECK_ALWAYS_ON=1 -DENABLE_EGLIMAGE=1 -DCLD_VERSION=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DDISABLE_FTP_SUPPORT=1 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -Igen -I../../third_party/libyuv/include -I../../third_party/libyuv -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -Os -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -Wnewline-eof -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -arch arm64 -Wendif-labels -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-selector-type-mismatch -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -std=gnu++0x -stdlib=libstdc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-slp-vectorize -fcolor-diagnostics  -c ../../third_party/libyuv/source/scale_argb.cc -o obj/third_party/libyuv/source/libyuv.scale_argb.o
../../third_party/libyuv/source/scale_argb.cc:150:26: error: assigning to 'void (*)(const uint8 *, ptrdiff_t, int, uint8 *, int)' from incompatible type 'void (const uint8 *, int, int, uint8 *, int)': type mismatch at 2nd parameter ('ptrdiff_t' (aka 'long') vs 'int')
    ScaleARGBRowDownEven = filtering ? ScaleARGBRowDownEvenBox_NEON :
                         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[58/1912] LINK libvpx_obj_int_extract, POSTBUILDS
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As it turns out (**for now**) arm64 build is only possible for the following environment:

OS X Version 10.9.5

Xcode Version: 6.1.1

So this morning I tried to pull and build latest release (at that time - r8053) following instructions from http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios

and it seemed to build OK except for 2 warnings:

```
1622/2019] CC obj/chromium/src/net/third_party/nss/ssl/libssl.sslmutex.o
../../chromium/src/net/third_party/nss/ssl/sslmutex.c:522:14: warning: 'sem_init' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        rv = sem_init(&pMutex->u.sem, shared, 1);
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/semaphore.h:55:5: note: 'sem_init' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int sem_init(sem_t *, int, unsigned int) __deprecated;
    ^
../../chromium/src/net/third_party/nss/ssl/sslmutex.c:544:7: warning: 'sem_destroy' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        rv = sem_destroy(&pMutex->u.sem);
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/semaphore.h:53:5: note: 'sem_destroy' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
int sem_destroy(sem_t *) __deprecated;
    ^
2 warnings generated.
[2019/2019] STAMP AppRTCDemo.app
```

but for old revision, still can't build arm64 libraries (some error regarding libyuv when building)

so my questions are:

1. is it at all possible to build arm64 libraries for revisions from a few months back such as 6881???
2. How to fetch older revision with the new fetch method ?

Thank you

Comment: The compiler error points to an error in the code of libvpx and not a missing dependency. Can you try some older/newer revision? For example 6870 or 6900 or even 7000.

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov, I tried pulling r6915. messages in the changes logs mentioned some changes regarding libvpx.gyp so i thought it might help, but still similar error when compiling.

Comment: @Guy I am using 10.10 and 6.1 versions can I do compilation successfully? Right now I am getting same error                                                    ScaleARGBRowDownEven = filtering ? ScaleARGBRowDownEvenBox_NEON :
                         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     any solution?

Comment: I have serached for a webRTC room , I didn't find in stack overflow.Is there any other place to ask my questions about webRTC.... :-)

Comment: AFAIK, for now, arm64 build will only work with 10.9.5 and 6.1.x. I couldn't get it to build for the old revision but I managed to build arm64 + armv7 for a more recent revision.
Any questions regarding Webrtc you can ask in the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc